# Errors in `term_sendkeys()`

Tags: terminal-buffer, error

`:h terminal-to-job` shows the following example of `term_sendkeys()`

```
call term_sendkeys(buf, "ls *.java\<CR>")
```

Following this, I added the line to `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <Leader>test :call term_sendkeys(2, "ls *.txt\<CR>")
```

where `2` is the buffer number.

After `:terminal`, running the command gives an error message:

```
E114: Missing double quote: "ls *.txt\
E116: Invalid arguments for function term_sendkeys
```

But, the command works fine if it is used directly in the command mode.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `mapping` call the line is interpreted slightly differently (focusing on keyboard input)

I would do:

```
nnoremap <Leader>test :call term_sendkeys(2, "ls *.txt<C-v><CR>")<CR>
```

The right hand side here is not the code itself but the keyboard sequence needed to input it. Furthermore the `<.>` construct are interpreted as keyboard input.

Your version was equivalent to:

```
:call term_sendkey(2, "ls *.txt\^M
")
```

The code proposed will lead to:

```
:call term_sendkey(2, "ls *.txt^M")
```